# backend shop. Showing certain products

Tags: node.js, mongoose, backend, ejs

I'm new to backend and I'm confused about how shops load (for example) 20 products, then when you click onto the next page you get 20 more new products.. I'm using nodejs with mongoose and ejs, so if anyone could submit an example with explanation I would really appriciate it! But an explanation only would also work! Thank's in advance! (I don't really know how to google the answer for this question, so that's why I'm here!)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to store the product details in a collection first . You can accomplish this by adding a form on the admin route . To store the image if you are using express you can use a middleware called `express-fileupload` then in your app.js file  `var fileupload = require("express-fileupload");` then you can register the middleware by `app.use(fileupload());` in your app.js file

To save the image here i am storing the image in server itself but this is not recommended . You want to rename the image with a connection . for eg the mongo document inserted id . This will really help you to loop products easily
i will show you an example on how to add the data from form to db and store the image with the mongo id.

```
router.post('/add-products', (req, res) => {
let datainsert = req.body,
db.get().collection('products').insertOne(datainsert).then((data) => {
    let id = data.insertedId
    let image = req.files.image
    image.mv('./public/images/product-images/' + id + '.jpg', (err) => {
        if (!err) {
           console.log("document added and image saved)
            res.redirect('/')
        } else {
            console.log("err" + err);
        }
    })
})
```

Now your product will be added to db and the image will be stored in server .
To view the products you can basically loop through the documents

hope it helped you if you face any errors or doubts feel free to reply . Thanks !

Comment: Thank you so much! But how can I only load 20 of my products in the database, and then when the user visits the next page i want to load 20 more that have not yet been shown? For example, if I have 40 products in my mongo database, then I want the first page to show the first 20 products in the database and then I want the next page to show the other 20 products in my database?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I can hide all products, then store them in an array and use this code to only show 5 new products in the list every time the query parameter "page" goes up. Here's the code: (its a bit janky but it does the job, and it might help someone who's looking for the same answer as me! Happy coding!

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  let query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  let pageNum = query.split("=")[1];
  return pageNum * 5;
}
let pageNum = getQueryVariable("page");

let namn = [];
let namnAttSamla = document.getElementsByClassName("namn");
for (let i = 0; i < namnAttSamla.length; i++) {
  namn.push(namnAttSamla[i].innerText);
}

for (let i = pageNum++; i < pageNum + 4; i++) {
  console.log(namnAttSamla[i].innerText, "index:", i);
}
```